# Android NDK: Fatal signal 11 + including the header

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have a question with regards to the android ndk. Since this is my first application, I wrote an equivalent C++ application and ran it first on my computer, to make sure that there are no logical errors. I use the g++-4.6 compiler. The program ran perfectly. So I set out to write the Android couterpart, and I ran into a few problems. When I run `ndk-build` in the command line, the program compiles. But when I side-load the program onto my android, I get the Fatal Signal 11 (SIGSEGV) error. Here is my `Android.mk` file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_native_method.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := header.h
LOCAL_MODULE := com_native_method
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I learned android development through youtube and online forums, and I understand that you have to use equivalent types (jint, jdouble, ... etc). But when I run ndk-build in such a case, I notice that I get errors telling me that `jint` and `jdouble` are not defined in `file2.cpp` and `file3.cpp`, so I changed them back to int, double, while keeping the types in com_native_method.cpp as jdouble and jint. I really can't figure out the problem.

Would appreciate the help,

Thanks,

naxchange

Comment: If you post the java files containing the native methods and the c files with those methods we might be able to help you better

Comment: Oh man! I posted this a long time ago! I think the problem was that I forgot to call `System.loadLibrary("...");`, but +1 for looking for my old, unanswered question and offering a hand